# Moving a shape and having the other one follow it

Tags: processing, shapes

I am trying to draw a number of shapes in processing which react to each others movements. So when I move one of them, it is connected to say 1 or 2 of the other shapes in the sketch. However I don't want it to be a static movement, I want it to look quite natural.

The only code I have at the moment is basic drawing of a shape which moves when you drag it, but have no idea how to link shapes :( Help!!

```java
float bx;
float by;
int boxSize = 75;
boolean overBox = false;
boolean locked = false;
float xOffset = 0.0; 
float yOffset = 0.0;

void setup() 
{
  size(640, 360);
  bx = width/2.0;
  by = height/2.0;
  rectMode(RADIUS);  
}

void draw() 
{ 
  background(0);

  // Test if the cursor is over the box 
  if (mouseX > bx-boxSize && mouseX < bx+boxSize && 
      mouseY > by-boxSize && mouseY < by+boxSize) {
    overBox = true;  
      }
  // Draw the box
  rect(bx, by, boxSize, boxSize);
}

void mousePressed() {
  if(overBox) { 
    locked = true; 
  } else {
    locked = false;
  }
  xOffset = mouseX-bx; 
  yOffset = mouseY-by; 
}

void mouseDragged() {
  if(locked) {
    bx = mouseX-xOffset; 
    by = mouseY-yOffset; 
  }
}

void mouseReleased() {
  locked = false;
}
```

I am thinking I need to use PShape, but am unsure.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend you to use a class for the shapes, that way you can link them easily.
I make some changes in your code in order to get some kind of following behaviour.

```java
class Box{
  float bx;
  float by; 
  int size = 75;

  Box(float bx, float by){
    this.bx = bx;
    this.by = by;   
  }

  void drawBox(){
    rect(bx, by, size, size);
  }

  void moveBox(float x, float y){
    bx = bx + x;
    by = by + y; 
  }

}



boolean overBox = false;
boolean locked = false;
float xOffset = 0.0; 
float yOffset = 0.0;
Box box, secondBox, thirdBox;

void setup() 
{
  size(640, 360); 
  box = new Box(width/2.0, height/2.0); 
  secondBox = new Box(100, 100);
  thirdBox = new Box(500, 300);  
  rectMode(RADIUS);  
}

void draw() 
{ 
  background(0);

  // Test if the cursor is over the box 
  if (mouseX > box.bx-box.size && mouseX < box.bx+box.size && 
      mouseY > box.by-box.size && mouseY < box.by+box.size) {
    overBox = true; 
    box.drawBox();   
    secondBox.drawBox();
    thirdBox.drawBox();   
  }

}

void mousePressed() {
  if(overBox) { 
    locked = true; 
  } else {
    locked = false;
  }
  xOffset = mouseX-box.bx; 
  yOffset = mouseY-box.by; 
}

void mouseDragged() {
  if(locked) {
    box.bx = mouseX-xOffset; 
    box.by = mouseY-yOffset; 

    deltaMovemente(box, secondBox);
    deltaMovemente(box, thirdBox);
  }
}

void mouseReleased() {
  locked = false;
}

void deltaMovemente(Box follow, Box box){
  float dx = (follow.bx - box.bx)/50;
  float dy = (follow.by - box.by)/50;

  box.moveBox(dx, dy);
}
```

Hope this can be useful.
Regards.